# how do i pass parameter or ajax data to a python script using ajax call in javascript and get response if it is successful?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax

I want to pass all parameter used in an ajax call in jquery to a python file or script which I am using to communicate with the database and doing all the computation at once and updating or sending those calculation to the database or directly sending the response to the ajax call on success. I have added an example jquery and python code which has no parameter passed into it. But i want to pass data in the python script if user makes any changes.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#filter_graph_by_date').click(function(){ 
                      
        var from_date =$('#start_date').val();

        var to_date =$('#end_date').val();
                    
        var customer =$('#customer_filters').val();
                            
        var machine =$('#machine_filters').val();
         
        var cytype = $('#cyType_filters').val();

        var cystatus = $('#cyStatus_filters').val(); 
            
        var net = $('#ByNetWts').val(); 

        var res = $('#ByResWts').val();
                      
        if(from_date != '' && to_date != ''){
                        
            $.ajax({  

                url:"statistics.py",  
                            
                type:"POST",

                dataType:"json",

                data: { 

                    from_date: from_date, 

                    to_date: to_date,
                                
                    customer: customer, 
                    
                    machine: machine,

                    cytype: cytype, 

                    cystatus: cystatus,
                    
                    net:net,
                    
                    res:res,

                 },      
                        
                           
                 success: function(data) {
      
                 },
                            
                 error: function(data) {

                     console.log(data);

                 }
                          
             })

         }

     })
                    
})
```

```js
import os, sys, time
import pymysql
from json2html import *
import string

PRJ_DB = 'plcproject'
                        
def get_values_Keys(band_limit, first_key, last_key, frm, to, keys, diff): 
    col_limit = {};
    key_vals = {};
    key_vals[first_key] = 0;
    key_vals[last_key] = 0;
    lastKey_count = 0;
        
        for key in keys:
            col_limit[key] = [(key - band_limit), (key + band_limit)];
            key_vals[str(key)] = 0;
        
     
        for dif_val in diff: 
            val = dif_val;
            if (val < frm):
                key_vals[first_key] += 1;
            elif (val > to):
                lastKey_count += 1;
            else:
                for key in keys: 
                    if ((val >= col_limit[key][0]) and (val < col_limit[key][1])):
                        key_vals[str(key)] += 1;
                        break;
                    

        
        key_vals[last_key] = lastKey_count;
        out_row = {};
        cnt = 0;
        #final_row = []
        out_row[cnt] = [ first_key, key_vals[first_key]];
        #final_row.append(key_vals[first_key])
        cnt = 1;       
        for key in keys:
            #print("Key:", key)
            out_row[cnt] = [str(key), key_vals[str(key)]];
            #final_row.append(key_vals[str(key)])
            cnt += 1;
        
        out_row[cnt] = [last_key, key_vals[last_key]];
        #final_row.append(key_vals[last_key])
        #print("Final Row:", final_row) 
        return out_row;
    
def get_average_key_val(mc, keyVals):
    keyVals_list = []
    key_val_dict = {}
    keys = []
    vals = []
    mult_items = 0
    sum = 0
    cnt = 0
    keyVals_list = list(keyVals.values())[1:][:-1]
    
    for item in keyVals_list:
        key, val = item[0], item[1]
        keys.append(key)
        vals.append(val)
        sum+=val
        try:
            prod = int(key)*int(val)
            mult_items+=prod
            if prod:
                cnt+=1
        except:
            continue
    i = 0
    key_val_dict['machine'] = mc
    for key in keys:
        key_val_dict[key] = vals[i]
        i+=1
        
    key_val_dict['sum'] = sum
    try:
        key_val_dict['Average'] = "{:.2f}".format(mult_items/cnt)
    except:
        key_val_dict['Average'] = 0
    
    return key_val_dict
    
    
    
    
        
        
    
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    mydb = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", database=PRJ_DB)
    db_coursor = mydb.cursor()
    db_coursor.execute("SELECT differences, machine FROM productiondetail WHERE status = 1")
    data_rows = db_coursor.fetchall()
    machine_list = []
    diff_rows = []
    
    for data in data_rows:
        #0 --> rangefrom  1--> rangeto, 2--> leastcount
        diff_rows.append(data[0])
        machine_list.append(data[1])
        
    #print(diff_rows, machine_list)
        
    cnt = 0
    mc_diff = {}    
    for mc in machine_list:
        try:
            mc_diff[mc].append(diff_rows[cnt])
        except:
            print("First value for ", mc)
            mc_diff[mc] = []
            mc_diff[mc].append(diff_rows[cnt])
        cnt+=1
    
    
    db_coursor.execute("SELECT rangefrom, rangeto, leastcount FROM othersettings WHERE id = 1");
    data_rows = db_coursor.fetchall()
    for data in data_rows:
        #0 --> rangefrom  1--> rangeto, 2--> leastcount
        rangefrom = int(data[0])
        rangeto = int(data[1])
        leastcount = int(data[2])
        band_limit  = leastcount / 2;
        first_key = '<'+str(rangefrom);
        last_key = '>'+str(rangeto);

        print("==== ", rangefrom, rangeto, leastcount) 

    keys = [];
    key_vals_dict_list = []
    key_vals_dict = {}; 
    
    cnt = 0
    for i in range(rangefrom, rangeto, leastcount):
        #print(i)
        keys.append(i)
        cnt += 1
    
    final_lst = []
    
    sum_avg = ['sum', 'Average']
    header = ['Machine_range']+keys + sum_avg
    final_lst.append(header)
    header_len = len(header)
    for mc in mc_diff:
        #print("Machine %s Graph Array List :" %mc)
        key_vals_array = get_values_Keys(band_limit, first_key, last_key, rangefrom, rangeto, keys, mc_diff[mc]);
        #print (key_vals_array)
        #print()
        tmp = get_average_key_val(mc, key_vals_array)
        final_lst.append(tmp.values())
        key_vals_dict_list.append(tmp)
    
    
    #print("Full Graph Array List:")
    key_vals_array = get_values_Keys(band_limit, first_key, last_key, rangefrom, rangeto, keys, diff_rows);
    #print (key_vals_array)
    #print()
    
    temp = get_average_key_val('Total', key_vals_array)
    tot_perc = dict(temp)
    
    tot_vals = temp.values()
    final_lst.append(tot_vals)
    
    tot_sum = temp['sum']
    for k, v in temp.items():
        #print("++++++++",k, v)
        if v == 'Total':
           tot_perc[k] = "Total %"
        elif k == 'sum':
            tot_perc[k] = 100
        elif k == 'Average':
           tot_perc[k] = ""
        elif isinstance(v, int):
            try:
                tot_perc[k] = "{:.2f}".format((v/tot_sum) * 100)
            except:
                tot_perc[k] = 0.0
        else:
            continue
            
            key_vals_dict_list.append(temp)
            key_vals_dict_list.append(tot_perc)
            final_lst.append(tot_perc.values())
            #for k, v in temp.items():

            input = {"statistics":key_vals_dict_list}
            #print(input)
            html_data = json2html.convert(json = input)
            fo = open("test.html", 'w')
            fo.write(html_data)
            fo.close()
            #print(final_lst)

            #Clear DB Table
            sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE statistics"
            db_coursor.execute(sql)
            mydb.commit()

            #create Table array elements;
            chr_set = string.ascii_lowercase[:header_len]
            c_len = 26 - header_len
            ch_ar = ""
            for i in range(c_len):
                ch_ar += ' ,'
            ch_ar= ch_ar.strip(",")

            stat_sql = "INSERT INTO statistics (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f`, `g`, `h`, `i`, `j`, `k`, `l`, `m`, `n`, `o`, `p`, `q`, `r`, `s`, `t`, `u`, `v`, `w`, `x`, `y`, `z`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)";
            for data in final_lst:
                data=list(data)+ch_ar.split(",")
                for i in range(0, len(data)): 
                    data[i] = str(data[i]) 
                #Update new values
                data = tuple(data)
                #print(stat_sql)
                print(data)
                db_coursor.execute(stat_sql, data)
                mydb.commit()
```

Comment: What Python framework are you using? Flask or Django?

Comment: hi @SeyiDaniel I have not writen or coded the above python script by myself i am not python coder but i think its flask

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. using data: JSON.stringify

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#filter_graph_by_date').click(function(){ 
                      
        var from_date =$('#start_date').val();

        var to_date =$('#end_date').val();
                    
        var customer =$('#customer_filters').val();
                            
        var machine =$('#machine_filters').val();
         
        var cytype = $('#cyType_filters').val();

        var cystatus = $('#cyStatus_filters').val(); 
            
        var net = $('#ByNetWts').val(); 

        var res = $('#ByResWts').val();
                      
        if(from_date != '' && to_date != ''){
            $.ajax({
                url: '"statistics.py"',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify( {  from_date: from_date, 

                    to_date: to_date,
                                
                    customer: customer, 
                    
                    machine: machine,

                    cytype: cytype, 

                    cystatus: cystatus,
                    
                    net:net,
                    
                    res:res } ),
                
                processData: false,
                success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
                    $('#response pre').html( JSON.stringify( data ) );
                },  
                error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                    console.log( errorThrown );
                }
           });
```

Comment: And how i am suppose to use this data in the python script if you could help me with that

Comment: This might help you . you need to wrap it in something like flask. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/jquery/